# Cant resize an UIImage properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an updateUI method for playing cards game and I added an image for the back of the card but the picture is all over the place and I cant fint the problem..

This is my method: how do i resize it to to match the card size?

```
- (void)updateUI {

    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons) {
        Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton]];
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents
                    forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];
        cardButton.selected = card.isFaceUp;
        cardButton.enabled = !card.isUnplayable;
        cardButton.alpha = card.isUnplayable ? 0.3 : 1.0;

        cardButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2);
        UIImage *cardBackImage = (cardButton.selected) ? nil : [UIImage imageNamed:@"benCardImag.png"];
        [cardButton setImage:cardBackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    self.scoreCounter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", self.game.score];

    if (self.game.notification) {

        self.notificationLabel.text = self.game.notification;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setBackgroundImage:forState:` instead of `setImage:forState:`. The image is adjusted to the left of the text, but the background image is scaled to fill the button. You may also want to try a custom UIControl instead of an UIButton if you want to control the placement of the images and text.

Comment: cool thanks allot, but can I also make the bg image with rectangle corners lic the actual cardbutton? so the bg image would actually look like the card and not just a square bg. also when I click on it its giving me back the card shape so it looks funky..

Comment: Try setting the button layer's cornerRadius and using a custom button instead of a RoundRect button. If that doesn't work you will probably have to implement your own button.

Comment: when you say "your own" you mean like design something with photoshop? @Aleph

Comment: You can probably get away with setting the corner radius and border color to a UIControl. Just create a UIControl subclass.